# Transposing a dataframe with column 0 entries as new column names and column 1 entries as their respective values

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to change the dataframe such that the values in column 0 are new columns with there repective values coming from same index at column 1 for example for column name Agreement Number its value would be 59598840.So basically transposing this dataframe
Could anybode tell how to do it?

[image: Making the elements at column 0 as column names with there respective values at column 1]

Comment: Hi, please avoid posting a picture, but post your data in code. Also, `df.T` will transpose columns to rows and rows to columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`df.set_index(0).transpose()`

This sets your first column as an index and transposes a dataframe to give you desired column structure.